# Django - Populate Field with data anothe field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a Custom User Class inside the APP Core.

Within APP Management I have a `Person` Class.
My `Core.User` Class has connection to the `Management.Person` Class.
Within the two Classes I have an email field

this email will serve as the login for the system.

What I need to do is:

When registering a User, the first thing to do is select the Person. and I need the `User` email field to receive the same email that is in the `Person` class

How to do this?

Comment: Can you share the relevant (parts of the) models, views, forms, etc.? This will probably make things easier.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry, but I did not understand

Comment: @CristopherWerner you need to post some relevant code, like the models, so people can get a  better understanding of your question.